# Using geolocation and geocoder to locate the user's city and assign it to a variable

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm trying to locate the user's city and assign it to a global variable for further usage. I'm able to get the city by using geolocation and geocoder and alerting it out. My problem is.. how do I assign the return city to a global variable so i can use it outside the `getCity` function? Here's my code that will alert the user's current city location.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
//get city fucntion
function getCity() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPos);
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
}

//callback function to get lat and long
function showPos(position) {

    // lat and long
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lng = position.coords.longitude;

    //new geocoder to reverse geocoding
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    //set lat and long
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    //get address
    geocoder.geocode({
        'location': latlng 
    }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            if (results[0]) {
                //get city
                alert(results[0]['address_components'][2].long_name);
            }
        }
    });//end geocoder callback

}//end showPos callback

getCity();

</script>
```

Code above will alert the user's city. Now I want the city to be assigned to a global variable so I can use it for something else. I've tried declaring a variable outside of the `getCity()` function and assigning it to `results[0]['address_components'][2].long_name`; like so...

```
var city;
function getCity() {
    city = results[0]['address_components'][2].long_name;
}
alert(city);
```

This doesn't do anything. Can someone give me some suggestions?

Comment: You need to consume the data in the callback since geocoder is asynchronous. Your alert will fire before the data is returned

Comment: Can give me an example? I don't know what you mean by consume the data. I've tried putting all my other codes that uses the 'city' result inside the the callback and it works. Is there a way that I can use the result outside the callback?

Comment: No.. you can't use it until it has been returned

Comment: duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be more explicit, you **can** use it outside the callback, but you have to **wait for the callback to have been executed**, so that your global variable is now assigned the correct value.

For example, see these situations:

```js
var city;

function getCity() {
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPos);
    } else { 
        x.innerHTML = "Geolocation is not supported by this browser.";
    }
    alert(city); // shows "undefined" when called the first time
}

function showPos(position) {
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lng = position.coords.longitude;
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);

    geocoder.geocode({'location': latlng}, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK && results[0]) {
            //get city
            city = results[0]['address_components'][2].long_name;
            alert(city); // shows the found city.
            showCity(); // shows the found city.
        }
    });
}

getCity();

function showCity() {
    alert(city);
}

showCity(); // shows "undefined" when called here.
```

Please read the post recommended by geocodezip in your question comments. Once you understand Asynchronous tasks in JavaScript, everything will make more sense.